# Which IO read/write characteristic is more important for Virtual machine type 2: 4K or sequential

Tags: virtual-machines, performance-tuning

IO devices often specify their characteristics in terms of:

- sequential read/write;
- 4K read/write;

Which characteristic is more important for performance of Virtual machine type 2 (like VirtualBox which runs on top of host operation system) :

- 4K or sequential?
- read or write?

Comment: Please take this discussion to meta.SF. Question comments are not places for extended discussion.